# How can electric flux be negative?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conventions

If electric flux is the number of field lines, then how can it be negative?

Comment: The orientation of the field lines is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a sphere, inside this sphere, in the center you put an electron. The flux will point towards the electron, so all lines are going to the electron, and through the sphere.

Now swap the electron for a proton, all lines stay the same, except that now they point outwards. The flux has changed direction! To quantify this, one uses positive and negative signs.

Answer (score 1):

When we calculate the flux of a vector field we have to specify a surface through which the vector field is passing. We then have to specify which direction through the surface we want to define as "positive flux". Once we have made this choice, any flux passing in the opposite direction through the surface is defined as "negative flux".

To relate this to something in physics, if we enclose a positively charged particle inside of a sphere and ask what is the flux of the electric field it produces through the surface of the sphere we have to decide whether flux **out of** the sphere is going to be "positive" or "negative". Typically in this case we define "outward" flux to be positive, in which case the total electric flux through the surface will be a positive number since the electric field lines point **out** of a positively charged particle. If we repeated the same experiment with a negatively charged particle we would get a negative answer.

Here is an image that illustrates the field lines and their direction for positively and negatively charged particles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flux is not really the number of field lines passing through the surface. There are an *infinite* number of field lines because one passes through every point. Illustrations of field lines show only a finite number of them.

Electric flux is the surface integral of the normal component of the electric field, $\int\vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}\,dA$, and this can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of electric flux:
$$Ф=\vec{E}\cdot\vec{S}=ES\cos(\widehat{\vec{E}\vec{S}})$$
where $\vec{S}=S\cdot\hat{n}$, $\hat{n}$ unit normal vector to the surface, $\widehat{\vec{E}\vec{S}}$ is the angle between $\vec{E}$ and $\hat{n}$. Flux is positive if it is exiting from the surface, negative when it is entering the surface.

Comment: I would suggest it depends upon you that you treat incoming Flux as positive or not!